# Twin prime conjecture (Goldbach-Collatz remix)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, collatz-conjecture, goldbachs-conjecture

Assuming Goldbach's conjecture, let's denote $r_{0}(n)$ for any integer $n$ greater than $1$ the smallest non negative integer $r$ such that both $n+r$ and $n-r$ are primes. Let $f$ be the map $m\mapsto m.r_{0}(m)$ if $m>1$ and $m\mapsto 0$ otherwise. Is it true that there are infinitely many twin primes if and only if for all non negative integer $m$, the sequence $(u_{n}(m))$ with $u_{0}(m)=m$ and $u_{n+1}(m)=f(u_{n}(m))$ is bounded?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there are finitely many twin primes, then in particular, since $f(m) \ge m$ for all composite $m$ with equality iff $r_0(m) = 1$, there exists $m$ sufficiently large such that $r_0(u_n(m))>1$ for all $n$, and hence $u_n(m)$ is unbounded. I think that the converse is probably false, since even if there are infinitely many twin primes, they are still extremely sparse, and for each pair of twin primes, there is exactly one $m$ such that $r_0(m) = 1$.

Comment: What I mean is: Twin prime conjecture holds if and only if $\forall m,\exists C_m\geq 0,\lim_{n\to\infty}u_{n}(m)=C_m$.

Comment: No, it isn't. Whenever an $m$ such that $r_{0}(m)=1$ is reached, the sequence remains constant without being equal to $0$.

Comment: Why the collatz-tag ? I do not see where collatz's conjecture plays a role here.

Comment: Well, Collatz' conjecture deals with conjecturally bounded sequences of integers too. It's just an analogy, don't worry too much about it.

Comment: @SylvainJulien To clarify, I was saying that if the twin prime conjecture is false, then we can show that the sequences are always bounded. However, I that the converse is probably false, since even if the twin prime conjecture is true,  it seems unlikely that for every $m$, there is some $n$ such that $u_n(m)$ is sandwiched between two twin primes, which is what you would require for the sequence to be bounded.

Comment: @Sylvain: Ah! Right you are.

Comment: @Mathmo123: I'm not sure why monotonicity didn't occur to me, but you're quite right.